# File name validation with extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate a file name in javascript.

The characters that I want to allow are: any letters, any numbers, underscores and hyphens.

I want to alert the user if this condition is not met. I thought I had a regex that would do the job based on some online regex testers, but it isn't working.

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/8g65yuu6/

```
var filename = 'index.html';

if (filename.match(/^(?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.html$/)) {
  alert('Success: valid');
} else {
  alert('Error: invalid');
}
```

I was hoping this would validate a html file, the condition is never met.

Comment: If I want to validate the file, I'll only check extension. Why force rules on the filename. Change it after file is uploaded. Use `/\.html$/i.test(filename)`.

Comment: I need to validate the whole thing otherwise user's don't recognise their files once I've remove spaces, parenthesis, illegal charters etc.

Comment: What about with just using `/^([\w_\-]+)\.html$/`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gT0xR7/1)

Comment: @empiric The regex can be simplified as `/^[\w-]+\.html$/i`.

Comment: You can store the original file name as metadata. I would expect any website to at least to be able to handle spaces and parentheses in file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work, and is a lot simpler:

```
var filename = 'index.html';

if (filename.match(/^([\w\-]+)\.html$/)) {
  alert('Success: valid');
} else {
  alert('Error: invalid');
}
```

Not sure why you have the 2 separate clauses:

```
(?:[\w]\:|\\)
```

and

```
(\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)
```

Also, the `+` after the last clause will always cause it to fail

Comment: Thanks - I used your example and removed the `\s` and `\.` as you suggested.  https://jsfiddle.net/8g65yuu6/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the filename contains valid characters no matter their order you can simplify your regex to:

`/^([\w\-]+)\.html$/`

Explanation:
 Captures one ore more characters which are

- any word character (same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- the hyphen `-`

Updated Code:

```
var filename = 'index.html';

if (filename.match(/^([\w\-]+)\.html$/)) {
  alert('Success: valid');
} else {
  alert('Error: invalid');
}
```

[Demo of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/gT0xR7/2)

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g65yuu6/2/)

Comment: That would fail for filenames with more than one period `.`, also it doesn't include spaces `\s`

Comment: `\w = [a-zA-Z0-9_]` so `_` is not needed in group. `-` does not need to be escaped when it is the first/last character in the character class. Use `i` flag. Use `test` instead of `match`.

Comment: @mikeyq6 as OP said `The characters that I want to allow are: any letters, any numbers, underscores and hyphens.` So for my understanding no `.` and whitespaces are allowed

Comment: @empiric Good point. It's not clear what is being asked due to the disparity between the code and the question